# If $a^n-1$ divides $b^n-1$ too often, then $b=a^k$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, problem-solving

I am looking for references to the following problem, which I saw a long time ago and I think is a well-known problem (maybe from IMO or American Mathematical Monthly), I hope to remember it correctly.

**Problem.** Let $a$ and $b$ be two positive integers. If $a^n - 1$ divides $b^n - 1$ for all the positive integers $n$, then $b = a^k$ for some positive integer $k$.

Thank you in advance for any answer.

**EDIT:** As noted by cr001, a solution to the problem was given on Math.StackExchange (see [question 417340](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417340/do-there-exist-two-primes-pq-such-that-pn-1-mid-qn-1-for-infinitely-many?rq=1)). However, what I am asking for is a reference to a journal or book.

Comment: Did you make sure that this is not a duplicate ?

Comment: @Elaqqad duplicate of what? I didn't find the same question on math.stackexchange, pearphs there is, but I don't know.

Comment: I found a reference on this forum actually. The question is different but the answer solves the exact problem. (And I removed my incomplete solution as well, if anyone appears to work on my solution and managed to prove it please post a new answer.)

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417340/do-there-exist-two-primes-pq-such-that-pn-1-mid-qn-1-for-infinitely-many?rq=1

Comment: @cr001 Thank you, I'm gonna add the link you pointed out in my question.

Comment: It's known that if $b\neq a^k$ for every $k$ then $a^n-1$ can not divide $b^n-1$ infinitely often , as a reference you may look for "Hadamard Quotient Theorem" or some of it's generalizations which are transferred to the Diophantine equations

Comment: @Elaqqad You are right about Hadamard Quotient Theorem, but I am asking for a reference to the original problem with $a^n-1$ and $b^n-1$.

Comment: Here is a reference for [my claim](http://www.emis.de/journals/JTNB/2005-1/pages423-435.pdf) "but not the original one" (I did not find the original) see page $427-\cdots$, The proof is not quite elementary it uses some analysis and a well known theorem due to  Wolfgang M. Schmidt  called Subspace theorem

Comment: Your title seems subjective. What is your definition of "too often?"