# Suppose $(a^n-1)\mid(b^n-1)$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Can we conclude that $b$ is a power of $a$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b$ be positive integers. Suppose $(a^n-1)\mid(b^n-1)$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Can we conclude that $b$ is a power of $a$?

Comment: what has been tried ?

Comment: I can prove that a prime factor of $b$ must be a factor of $a$. So the statement holds for the case $a$ is a prime number.

Comment: In my opinion is quite obviously true also the inverse:  if $b$ is a power of $a$ then $(a^n-1)\mid(b^n-1)$

Comment: @Zerinf Zhang ; See each of the following: 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461203/if-an-1-divides-bn-1-too-often-then-b-ak

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919550/if-fracan-1bn-1-is-a-natural-number-for-every-n-then-a-bm?noredirect=1&lq=1

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417340/do-there-exist-two-primes-pq-such-that-pn-1-mid-qn-1-for-infinitely-many/1466790#1466790

Comment: @Famke - I haven't looked very carefully, but at first sight it's not clear to me that this is a duplicate.

Comment: @ Pierre-Yves Gaillard ; 
as Elaqqad has been mentioned; in page 27 of the following there is an answer for this problem:   
http://www.emis.de/journals/JTNB/2005-1/pages423-435.pdf

Comment: @Famke - Thanks! (I wasn't notified of your comment, perhaps because you put a space between @ and my name.)

Comment: @Pierre-Yves Gaillard ; yes, you are right.